# Does minimizing stages necessarily give best outcome when designing circuit under a delay constraint?

Tags: delay, energy, vlsi

In the context of digital design, a common situation is to have to design a circuit for minimum energy under a delay constraint. Suppose a given circuit can be implemented with various stages. Is it necessarily true that, if a circuit can be implemented to meet the delay constraint with a given number of stages \$n\$ and that this is the least such number, then this number of stages will also minimize the energy? This seems like a good heurisitic but I'm wondering if it is necessarily true given the dependence of sizes of each stage on the number of stages.

I can also give an example of what I mean as required, but it was a bit long and so I figured I'd omit it in a first pass.